# $http.get in Angular doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, yeoman

I have problem with `$http.get` when I am trying to get data from my DB ( mongoDB).

I'm using mean stack.

```
angular.module('wildroseApp')
.controller('WildroseComponent', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('/api/wildrose')
        .success(function (data) {
        $scope.wildrose = data;
        console.log($scope.wildrose);
    })
        .error(function (err) {
        alert('Error!');
    });
})
.component('wildrose', {
    templateUrl: 'app/wildrose/wildrose.html',
    controller: WildroseComponent,
    controllerAs: Wildrose
});
```

In addition, I have one more question:

When I'm using `controllerAs` in component, my browser says

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Wildrose is not defined

But, if remove it it would be OK.

I have tried solving it as follows:

Just add in the constructor a little bit code:

```
class WildroseComponent {
  constructor($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.wildrose = [];
  }
  $onInit(){
      this.$http.get('/api/wildrose')
          .then(response => {
              this.wildrose = response.data;
              console.log(this.wildrose);
          });;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of AngularJs are you using?

Comment: What is your question/problem? What "doesn't work" mean exactly?

Comment: when im getting data from my DB with $http.get 
nothing to show in console.log($scope.wildrose) but here should be json string

Comment: Please try to update your AngularJs to 1.5.7, HTH ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ControllerAs requires string and not an object:

```
controllerAs: "wildrose"
```

Have you set up an endpoint at your server with node/express under  `/api/wildrose` that returns a json string read from your database?

Please provide more code from your back-end and errors, otherwise it is hard to diagnose.

Comment: yep i made endpoint with yeoman generator 
 this is code from controller

// Gets a list of Wildroses
export function index(req, res) {
  return Wildrose.find().exec()
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
this is index.js 

router.get('/', controller.index);

 no error just nothing to show when i'm using $http.get

Comment: If you use chrome,  what is the network panel saying under dev tools?  The request sent correctly? What is the response saying from your back end?

Comment: One thing, I am not sure about MEAN, but mongodb's find method requires an object as argument. If you want to find all entries of a collection use an empty object .find({})